# Add condition in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables advert , application and people.

```
 Select * from advert v, application a 
 inner join people p on p.id = a.id 
 where v.id=a.id
```

This query returns me all application irrespective of the gender. But sometimes in the advert table, gender is specified as M. So now i want the query above return me only application made by M. To get this value i need to add one more condition, `p.gender = v.gender`. How do i do this? Sometimes the value of `v.gender = n/a`. Then I wont need this condition. It should return me all application irrespective gender.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but it seems you need a "Having" clause.

Comment: can you provide an example? I'm really stuck on this

Comment: Select * from advert v, application a inner join people p on p.id = a.id where v.id=a.id
having p.gender = v.gender   This should work.

Comment: It says 'not a GROUP BY expression'

Comment: How about this: 
Select * from advert v, application a inner join people p on p.id = a.id where v.id=a.id
and p.gender = v.gender

Comment: yes this will work if value of gender is M or F. but if value of gender is n/a then it wont works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116447/discussion-between-helloimdarius-and-alina).

Comment: Unrelated, but: do **not** mix implicit and explicit joins in the same statement. As a general rule: never put a comma in the `from` part.

Comment: HAVING clause is used only in aggregate queries - I don't see any aggregation occurring here hence the *NOT A GROUP BY* error.

Answer (score 1):

To get your desired results, you need to modify the join condition between `advert` and `people` to join the records in either case (`v.gender = 'n/a' or p.gender = v.gender`):

```
select *
  from advert v
  join application a
    on a.id = v.id
  join people p
    on p.id = a.id
   and (v.gender = 'n/a' or p.gender = v.gender)
```

Comment: Using an OR statement could cause a serious performance hit especially with large tables. what is different about the above and (v.GENDER = 'N/A' OR p.GENDER = v.GENDER) AND v.GENDER IN ('N/A',p.GENDER)

Comment: @Jeff: There is no difference.  Using `IN` is in effect the same as using an `OR`.  The execution plan should be exactly the same.

Comment: thanks mate - I always believed using IN was more efficient than using OR, I appreciate the added info from this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to what you are asking but here is something to start with. Some example data would also be helpful

```
select *
from advert v
inner join application a
on a.id  = v.id
inner join people p
on a.id = p.id
where p.gender = 'M';
```

or

```
 select *
from advert v
inner join application a
on a.id  = v.id
inner join people p
on a.id = p.id
where p.gender = v.gender;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use an IN operator thusly:

```
WHERE v.GENDER IN ('N/A',p.GENDER)
```

This would return all records where v.GENDER = 'N/A' or where v.gender = p.GENDER